# Trying to study shine MPEG Layer-III encoder - getting "redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'bool'"

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt-creator, mpeg

Greetings.

I am studying the way mpeg layer-III encoding works for an upcoming project. I downloaded the shine encoder as it is said to be the simpliest of all. http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/sources/shine.zip is the link.

I successfully compiled them in a standalone project but i need to be using them in a QT project.

I made new blank console project in QT 
and added as existing all the files that previously successfully compiled for me (files from shine.zip).

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "main.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
//    return a.exec();
    mainc(argc,argv);
}
```

This is main.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include "main.c"
#endif // MAIN_H
```

everything else is untouched (i mean, without those two files it compiled successfully and worked)

I am now getting error at this part

```
#ifndef bool
typedef unsigned char bool;   <--- "redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'bool'"
#endif
```

Before there was no error here. From what i understand a presence of one cpp file makes all the code compile as c++ and the shine code is c, not c++... Does it mean i cannot use c code in a project that uses QT classes QCoreApplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix C and C++ code in the same project, but you need to compile the C code with a C compiler. Rather than trying to include `main.c` from a C++ file, compile the C code separately, and declare any C functions you need to call from C++ as `extern "C"`, for example

```
extern "C" int mainc(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Okay i see, so, what i should have done, is make a header file which i include in my main.cpp file, this header file should do this declaration and then file with the same name as this header .c should contain implementation, right? I mean, now its working for me, but i cant be sure i did it right...

Answer (score 0):

Never include the implemenation file in the header file. The

```
#include "main.c"
```

is wrong. It would lead to an include recursion, if the `#ifdef MAIN_H` would not protect.

In your example `QCoreAppplication` is included twice what leads to the error message.

Comment: Thank you, i've read about header files now and i understand i was wrong with that one. So, if i get it right, when i include a .h file, compiler will automatically look in same name .c or .cpp file for code?